# Convert list to tree by descendants and ancestors

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, tree, traversal

I am trying to convert the list to a tree using descendants and ancestors params in the element:

I have for example something like this:

```
const itemToUpdate = {
  id: 1,
  ancestors: [
    {
      id: 2,
      ancestors: [
        {
          id: 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  descendants: [
    {
      id: 3,
      descendants: [
        {
          id: 5
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          descendants: [
            {
              id: 8
            },
            {
              id: 9
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 7
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const updatedItem = {
  id: 4,
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      children: [
        {
          id: 1,
          children: [
            {
              id: 3,
              children: [
                {
                  id: 5
                },
                {
                  id: 6,
                  children: [
                    {
                      id: 8
                    },
                    {
                      id: 9
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  id: 7
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

The point is that trees can be nested up to many levels. Additionally, there can be many ancestors and descendants on the level, so I need a more generic solution. The tree must be created upward from ancestors and downward from descendants.

I found a way to get descendants of the tree, but I still need to add to that ancestors on the top of this tree:

```
export const convertListToTree = <T extends ApiTree<T>>(list: Array<T>, key = 'ascendants'): Array<T> => {
  const getNestedItem = (path: Array<string>, tree: Array<T>): T => {
    const nestedItem = tree.find(nestedItem => nestedItem.id === path[0]);
    const newPath = path.slice(1);
    if (!newPath.length) {
      return nestedItem;
    } else if (nestedItem?.[key]) {
      return getNestedItem(newPath, nestedItem?.[key]);
    } else {
      return getNestedItem(newPath, tree);
    }
  };

  const sortListByPathLength = (list: Array<T>): Array<T> => {
    return sortBy(list, (item: T) => item.path?.length);
  };

  const addRootItem = (item: T, tree: Array<T>): void => {
    tree.push(item);
  };

  const addChildrenItem = (item: T, tree: Array<T>): void => {
    const parent = getNestedItem(item.path, tree);
    if (parent) {
      parent[key].push(item);
    } else {
      addRootItem(item, tree);
    }
  };

  const tree = [];
  if (list?.length) {
    const sortedList = sortListByPathLength(list);
    sortedList.forEach(item => {
      if (!item.path?.length) {
        addRootItem(item, tree);
      } else {
        addChildrenItem(item, tree);
      }
    });
  }
  return tree;
};
```

Any advice will be more than welcome.

Comment: what if you have more than one item? what have you tried?

Comment: sorry, what should happen, if a node has more than one ancestors? this is really important to the solution.

Comment: @NinaScholz Hmm that's a good question. I think that we should move one or more root levels lower, like in this article: https://shareablecode.com/snippets/binary-tree-upside-down-javascript-solution-XrMB-xRjG

Comment: It is not clear to me what should happen with multiple ancestors? What would then be the root of the tree? In my understanding there is no tree in that case, but an directed acyclic graph. Please edit your question and give an example of such input with the expected output.

Comment: @NinaScholz You're totally right, sorry.. Each node can have several descendants, but only one ancestor. I updated the example with this situation. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If there can only be one line of ancestors, then why are they arrays? That seems overkill... as they will always consist of exactly one object, and so we could just skip the array wrapper.

Comment: It's also hard for me to understand that, but this is how our API is designed, and we are not able to quickly change this parameter, because it was created by another company...

Comment: Has your question been answered satisfactory or are you still waiting for an answer?

Comment: No, the answer I got is perfect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is only **one ancestor** for each level, you could take a recursive function that keeps the children but returns the earliest ancestor node.

```js
const
    fn = ({ id, ancestors, descendants }, children) => {
        const node = { id };
        if (Array.isArray(children)) node.children = children;
        if (descendants) node.children = descendants.map(fn);
        return ancestors
            ? fn(ancestors[0], [node])
            : node;
    },
    data = { id: 1, ancestors: [{ id: 2, ancestors: [{ id: 4 }] }], descendants: [{ id: 3, descendants: [{ id: 5 }] }] },
    result = fn(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, cool. We must assume that there may be several descendants and ancestors at each level. But that's something 

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve there. Could you elaborate a bit further?
This is how you would convert your particular example if that helps.

```
function convert(item) {
  return {
    id: item.ancestors[0].id,
    children: [
      {
        id: item.id,
        children: [
          {
            id: item.descendants[0].id
          }
        ]
      }      
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The point is that trees can be nested up to many levels. Additionally, there can be many ancestors and descendants on the level, so I need a more generic solution. The tree must be created upward from ancestors and downward from descendants.

Comment: @Patryk, you could add this case to the question.

Comment: @Patryk could you give an example with more items in the arrays I'm not sure how you want to handle assigning the ids that could be tricky enough